# GAS Dashboard shows latest version in its history irrespective of the version that ran

Tags: google-apps-script, dashboard

When I publish a new version of a script, the dashboard view of executions shows that new version number even in runs that executed before the version was written. All lines show either "Head" or the latest version number. This appears to be a bug, but maybe I am misunderstanding the dashboard.

Comment: If you think it's a bug the submit it as an issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a programming question. You should provide this feedback through the https://script.google.com/home/executions top right corner question mark ( "?" ) button to the Google team.

Comment: Done as suggested